# How can I calculate the pressure at an arbitrary distance from an active spout pumping a compressible fluid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure

Say I have a vent pumping a compressible gas into a room.

The newly arrived gas will push the existing gas out of the way to an extent. But also both the new and existing gasses will become compressed.

I think the amount of movement, and also the amount of compression will be greater near the vent.

At a given instant, for any arbitrary point in the 3d space of the room, I would like to calculate the amount of compression of the gas at that location, and the movement(distance/time) of the gas at that location.

Is there an equation for this, where I can just plug in the variables?

Answer (score 0):

The particles of air in a room are moving at a speed near 500m/s.  For everyday movement of air in a room (speeds much slower than mach 1), this is fast enough that there is no "piling up" of air near the vent.  The loss of precision by assuming constant static pressure and density throughout the room should be minimal.

More important will be constrictions.  If the flow into the room is high, then the room will pressurize.  There will be a pressure gradient near where the air can leak to the outside.

Outside of very symmetric and constrained regions (like a pipe of known diameter and known pressures), the flow is going to be chaotic and dispersive.  Simple (linear) formulas will not exist.

Comment: the room/air is just a hypothetical example (perhaps a poor one) it was just to help illustrate my actual question - which is, how to calculate pressure/movement at any point along the gradient in a case where the standing fluid IS such that it "piles up"